# Symfony 2 Entity Field

Tags: symfony, entity, field

I am getting error when I am using following entity type field,
It is showing me select field fine but when I am trying to save it it is giving me following error

Code 1:

```
        ->add('agentFirstname', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AcmeClientBundle:Client',
            'property' => 'firstName',
        ))
```

> Error 1: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Acme\ClientBundle\Entity\Client could not be converted to string

When I am using second code then everything is working fine

Code 2:

```
           ->add('agentFirstname', 'text', array(
                    )
            )
```

Error 2: No Error

Please find my entity bellow

```
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="agent_firstname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $agentFirstname;
```

I want to make select field here for client first name entity which is here

```
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Symfony cannot access the `$firstName` property as its [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) is private.

You need to add a `getFirstName()` method to your Acme\ClientBundle\Entity\Client class.

```
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}
```

Now change your form code to:

```
->add('agentFirstname', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeClientBundle:Client', 'property' => 'getFirstName'
))
```

Comment: Should you use `'property' => 'firstName'`? `getFirstName` is the name of the function, not the name of the property.

Comment: You can use anything supported by PropertyAccess: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html so you're right, keeping it as `'property' => 'firstName'` should work too.